# Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products. An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown

Tags: 2010, cumulative-update

in sharepoint 2010 when i install cu feb 2016, i face below errors one by one in event viewer and  configuration wizard failed

Unable to create a Service Connection Point in the current Active Directory domain.
 Verify that the SharePoint container exists in the current domain and that you have rights to write to it.
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The object LDAP://CN=Microsoft SharePoint Products,CN=System,DC=xx,DC=xx,DC=local doesn't exist in the directory.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceConnectionPoint.Ensure(String serviceBindingInformation)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeTask.Run()

Database 'SharePoint_Config' on SQL Server instance '' is not empty and does not match current database schema

Database 'SharePoint_AdminContent' on SQL Server instance '' is not empty and does not match current database schema.

Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

.The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUpgradeJobDefinition (ID e5ea29ed-87b8-4f17-a5ad-b14e602ac78c) threw an exception. More information is included below.

Action 4.0.14.0 of Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPIisWebSiteWssSequence failed.

Comment: check this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/67903479-4fd3-4907-83ed-ee6388aa7c5a/unable-to-create-a-service-connection-point?forum=sharepointadmin

Comment: The SCP is not the error. The fact that it is looking at an existing Config/Admin db and attempting to make a new one *is*. Unless this is a brand new farm.

Comment: this is old farm and i am trying to add cumulative updates, it works for me when i stop sharepoint foundation web application service and run the configuration wizard and started sharepoint foundation web application service , but from web applications now not working from our load balancer but working internally